# How to convert byte array into Human readable format?

Tags: java

I am using "Blowfish" algorithm to encrypt and decrypt the contents of the text. I am embedding the encrypted contents in the image but while extracting I am getting the byte array which I am passing it to method **update** of class **Cipher**.

But the method returns me byte array which I want to convert back into Human readable form.
When I use **write** method of **FileOutputStream** it is working fine when a filename is provided.
But now I want to print it on the console in the human readable format.  How to get through this? I have tried for ByteArrayOutputStream too. But didn't work well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

String value = new String(byteArray);
```

Comment: IMHO, Blowfish's returned byte array can return byte values in the full byte range. This answer currently shows an example byte array from the "human-readable sub-range". Using `new String(byteArray);` does not necessarily (usually) produce a human-readable String.

Comment: It does not necessarily produce "human readable string". In my case, It generates many Non Keyboard Characters. I used `DESede` algorithm.

Comment: it will not be human readable. byte range is -128 .. 127. Negative numbers and everything 64+ would produce junk

Answer (score 8):

If all you want to do is see the numeric values you can loop through the array and print each byte:

```
for(byte foo : arr){
    System.out.print(foo + " ");
}
```

Or if you want to see hex values you can use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("%02x ", foo);
```

If you want to see the string that the byte array represents you can just do

```
System.out.print(new String(arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the bytearray into a string containing the hex values of the bytes
using this method. This even works on java < 6

```
public class DumpUtil {

     private static final String HEX_DIGITS = "0123456789abcdef";

     public static String toHex(byte[] data) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i != data.length; i++) {
            int v = data[i] & 0xff;

            buf.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt(v >> 4));
            buf.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt(v & 0xf));

            buf.append(" ");
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
System.out.printf( Arrays.toString( data ) );

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do a hexDump that byte array

```
private static final byte[] HEX_CHAR = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3',
            '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
public static final String dumpBytes(byte[] buffer) {
        if (buffer == null) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.setLength(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            sb.append((char) (HEX_CHAR[(buffer[i] & 0x00F0) >> 4]))
                    .append((char) (HEX_CHAR[buffer[i] & 0x000F])).append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a trivial task, as many people assume. Each byte has values ranging from -128 to 127. Most of them are non printable characters.

In order to encode bytes in a human readable format you should understand that there is only 62 alphanumeric characters. There is no way ONE BYTE will map to ONE human readable characters as there is more possible bytes than 62 characters human can easily read.

Bellow is a class I wrote that converts a byte array into a String using provided alphabet (or a default if none provided).

It does conversion in chunks from 1 to 7 input bytes. Could not use more than 7 bytes is it is max for the biggest Java long value. And I use long values when do conversion.

If chunk for example of size 5 than it needs 7 alphanumeric symbols to encode a chunk of 5 bytes. So size of output will be greater than size of input.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

/**************************************************************************************************************
 * Convert bytes into human readable string using provided alphabet.
 * If alphabet size 62 chars and byte chunk is 5 bytes then we need 7 symbols to encode it.
 * So input size will be increased by 40% plus 7 symbols to encode length of input
 *
 * Basically we do conversion from base255 (byte can has 255 different symbols) to base of a a size of the
 * given alphabet
 *
 * @author Stan Sokolov
 * 10/9/19
 **************************************************************************************************************/
public class HumanByte {
final static private Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(OsmRouting.class);

// those are chars we use for encoding
private final static String DEFAULT_ALPHABET = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

private char[] ALPHABET;
private int BASE;
private int[] POSITIONS;
private int CHUNK;
private int PW;
private long[] POWERS; // {916132832, 14776336, 238328, 3844, 62, 1};
private long[] MASKS; //(0xFF000000L & (input[0] << 24)) | (0xFF0000L & input[1] << 16) | (0xFF00L & input[2] << 8) | (0xFFL & input[3]);


/**************************************************************************************************************
 * Default constructor, with default alphabet and default chunk
 **************************************************************************************************************/
public HumanByte() {
    this(DEFAULT_ALPHABET, 5);
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
 *   Setup encoding using provided alphabet and chunk size
 **************************************************************************************************************/
public HumanByte(final String alphabet, int chunk) {
    if (chunk>7){
        chunk=7;
    }
    if (chunk<1){
        chunk=1;
    }
    this.ALPHABET = alphabet.toCharArray();
    BASE = alphabet.length();

    CHUNK = chunk;
    long MX = (long) Math.pow(255, CHUNK);
    PW = logBase(MX);
    int max=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length; i++) {
        if (max<ALPHABET[i]) max=ALPHABET[i];
    }
    POSITIONS = new int[max+1];
    logger.debug("BASE={}, MX={}, PW={}", BASE, MX, PW);
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length; i++) {
        POSITIONS[ALPHABET[i]] = i;
    }
    POWERS = new long[PW]; //these are the powers of base to split input number into digits of its base
    for (int i = 0; i < PW; i++) {
        POWERS[i] = (long) Math.pow(BASE, PW - i - 1);
    }
    MASKS = new long[CHUNK];
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; i++) { //this is how we are going to extract individual bytes from chunk
        MASKS[i] = (0xFFL << ((CHUNK - i - 1) * 8));
    }
}


/**************************************************************************************************************
 *  take bytes, split them in group by CHUNK, encode each group in PW number of alphabet symbols.
 **************************************************************************************************************/
public String encode(final byte[] input) {
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(); //will save output string here
    output.append(word(input.length)); // first write length of input into output to know exact size

    byte[] byte_word;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ) {
        byte_word = new byte[CHUNK];
        for (int j = 0; j < CHUNK; j++) {
            if (i < input.length) {
                byte_word[j] = input[i++]; //remove negatives
            }
        }
        final long n = bytes2long(byte_word); //1099659687880

        final char[] w = word(n);
        output.append(w);

    }
    return output.toString();
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
 *   decode input
 **************************************************************************************************************/
public byte[] decode(final String in) {
    final int size = (int) number(in.substring(0, PW).toCharArray());
    final byte[] output = new byte[size];

    int j = 0, k = in.length();
    for (int i = PW; i < k; i += PW) {
        final String w = in.substring(i, i + PW);
        final long n = number(w.toCharArray());
        for (byte b : long2bytes(n)) {
            if (j < size) {
                output[j++] = b;
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
 * @return take 4 numbers from 0 to 255 and convert them in long
 **************************************************************************************************************/
private long bytes2long(byte[] input) {
    long v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; i++) {
        v |= ((long) (input[i]+ 128) << (8 * (CHUNK - i - 1)) & MASKS[i]); //+128 to remove negatives
    }
    return v;
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
 * @return take 4 numbers from 0 to 255 and convert them in long
 **************************************************************************************************************/
private byte[] long2bytes(long input) {
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[CHUNK];
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; i++) {
        long x = MASKS[i] & input;
        long y = 8 * (CHUNK - i - 1);
        long z = (x >> y) - 128;
        bytes[i] = (byte) z;
    }
    return bytes;
}


/**************************************************************************************************************
 *  create word using given alphabet to represent given number built out of CHUNK bytes
 **************************************************************************************************************/
private char[] word(final long n) {
    final char[] output = new char[PW];
    long v=n;
    for (int i = 0; i < PW; i++) {
        final long pn = v / POWERS[i];
        output[i] = ALPHABET[(int) pn];
        long x = pn * POWERS[i];//900798402816 196327857024 2368963584 16134768 267696 1716 52
        v -= x;
    }
    return output;
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
 *   take string that contain number encoded in alphabet and return
 **************************************************************************************************************/
private long number(final char[] s) {
    long number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < PW; i++) {
        long x =  (long) POSITIONS[s[i]];
        long y = POWERS[i];
        long z = x*y;
        number +=  z;
    }
    return number;
}

private int logBase(long num) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(num) / Math.log(BASE));
}
}
```