# Reading InputStream bytes and writing to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, io, stream

I have code block to read mentioned number of bytes from an InputStream and return a byte[] using ByteArrayOutputStream. When I'm writing that byte[] array to a file, resultant file on the filesystem seems broken. Can anyone help me find out problem in the below code block.

```
public byte[] readWrite(long bytes, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; //8KB
    long numReads = bytes/maxReadBufferSize;
    long numRemainingRead = bytes % maxReadBufferSize;
    for(int i=0; i<numReads; i++) {
        byte bufr[] = new byte[maxReadBufferSize];
        int val = in.read(bufr, 0, bufr.length);
        if(val != -1) {
            bos.write(bufr);
        }
    }
    if(numRemainingRead > 0) {
        byte bufr[] = new byte[(int)numRemainingRead];
        int val = in.read(bufr, 0, bufr.length);
        if(val != -1) {
            bos.write(bufr);
        }
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: `bos.write(bufr)` should be `bos.write(bufr, 0, val)`, and similarly for the other write. You're not taking account of the actual length read, so you're writing garbage to the file. You should also loop with `while ((val = in.read(bufr)) > 0)`, not with a `for` loop, as you don't know in advance how many reads will be required. This also gets rid of the second block, as you will exhaust the input with the first block. And allocate the buffer before the loop, to create much less garbage.

Comment: I'm getting numBytes to be read as a param `long bytes` and I'm calculating no.of iterations by `long numReads = bytes/maxReadBufferSize;` and remaining bytes to read using `long numRemainingRead = bytes % maxReadBufferSize;` then why it fails that's what i don't understand.

Comment: I've told you why it fails, and also how to fix it. What didn't you understand about that?

Comment: I know other methods to read the data from stream using `while` loop As you said. but how can you read only a mentioned number of bytes alone from the stream? If i need to read only 1MB from a filestream of 5MB, how can you achieve this?

Comment: Something like `while (remaining > 0 && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(remaining, buffer.length))) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, count); remaining -= count; }` where `remaining` is initially the total number of bytes to read.

Comment: And if you're just writing the resulting byte array to a file, why the byte array? You can accomplish that without a `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all, and save yourself both time and space.

Comment: My usecase is not to write data to a file for debugging purpose only I've used that. I need to send data split by multiple chunks.

Comment: Could you explain, what do you mean under "resultant file on the filesystem seems broken"? Is your file binary, text?

Comment: @SternK It is broken because it contains extra junk, and the reason for that has already been given.

Comment: @SternK I've tried some image files and they're broken. Due to extra junk bytes written, as explained by user207421

Answer (score 1):

### My understanding of the problem statement

Read ***bytes*** number of bytes from the given ***InputStream*** in a ***ByteArrayOutputStream***. 
Finally, return a *byte array*.

### Key observations

- A lot of work is done to make sure bytes are read in chunks of 8KB. 
  Also, the last remaining chunk of odd size is read separately.
- A lot of work is also done to make sure we are reading from the correct offset.

### My views

- Unless we are reading a very large file (>10MB) I don't see a valid reason for reading in chunks of 8KB.
- Let Java libraries do all the hard work of maintaining offset and making sure we don't read outside limits.
  Eg: We don't have to give offset, simply do *inputStream.read(b)* over and over, the next byte array of size b.length will be read. Similarly, we can simply write to *outputStream*.

### Code

```
public byte[] readWrite(long bytes, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)bytes];

    is.read(buffer);
    bos.write(buffer);

    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

### References

[About InputStreams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-to-outputstream) 
[Byte Array to Human Readable Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141317/how-to-convert-byte-array-into-human-readable-format)